# obtaining the viewer extent of an ArcGIS portal page w/ python widget

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, arcgis-10.4, python-toolbox, widget

I will be hosting various locations of features on an ArcGIS portal page, and want to add a geoprocessing widget (Python toolbox) that will export those features currently seen in the viewer.

The widget will select features that exist within the current view, so I want to grab the coordinates of the viewer extent. I've searched extensively for some ArcPy/Python code that will simply get the *current* extent of the ArcGIS Portal viewer at the time the user clicks the widget... So they do not have to set a polygon or circle to grab features, it will simply record the extent coordinates of the viewer.

Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished? Is there an ArcPy command that is escaping me?